# Sequence in displaying results from mySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
        <div class="container-fluid projects-container">
            <div class="container projects-list">
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user_showcase";
$password = "password123";
$dbname = "data_showcase";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, name, description, link, date, image, size, picid FROM projects";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo " <div class='col-md-6 box' id='".$row["id"]."'><div class='project'><div class='image blurry' id='".$row["picid"]."' style='background: url(http://www.all-channels.com/projects/images/".$row["image"].") top center no-repeat;'></div><div class='description-small'>

        <h6>".$row["date"]."</h6> 
        <h2>". $row["name"]. "</h2>
        <p>". $row["description"]. "</p>        
        <a href=" . $row["link"] . " target='_blank' class='go'>Take a look</a></div></div></div> ";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
                $conn->close();
?>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Need a way to display information from mySQL database in bootstrap divs in the sequence:

1. First and the second row of the table to be displayed in two neighbour divs with class **col-md-6**.
2. Third row to be displayed in another div with class **col-md-12**
3. Then the information from the next two rows after col-md-12's one to be displayed in two col-md-6 again and sixth to be col-md-12.

I've already made the code that echoes all results in equal width columns.
Just don't know how to make it display them in different width divs in desired sequence.

Comment: Can you please add the code that you have tried. So that we will get to know what your trying to achieve and what you have tried.

Comment: Will the above type ie 3 rows will be constant all the time or may vary

Comment: Just posted my code, not sure what you mean by "3 rows will be constant".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way to achieve this

```
$counter = 1;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    /* If any particular pattern by which you will get to know whether the code is gonna go in 2 columns (col-md-6) or 1 column (col-md-12) */
    /* Based on your code pattern if the loop in divisible by 3 then its col-md-12 else its col-md-6. The following code does the trick for you */
    $columnCondition = ($counter % 3 == 0) ? 'col12' : 'col6';  
    switch($columnCondition){
        case 'col6':
            echo '<div class="col-md-6">';
                //Row value
            echo '</div>';
            break;

        case 'col12':
            echo '<div class="col-md-12">';
                //Row value
            echo '</div>';
            break;
    }
    $counter++;
}
```

Comment: https://ibb.co/j90Aiw - thats the pattern, don't need hardcoding cause I already have 95 rows in the table and in the future i'll need to add new one almost every day.